# implementing Gaussian Visible units c++

Tags: c++, gaussian

I have implemented the RBM with Binary data and it works. But now I have been trying to change my energy function so that it takes real data (Gaussian visible units RBM). But when I compile my code I get the following error:

```
 error C2661: 'pow' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
```

And bellow here is just the modified part of my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n_hidden; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n_visible; j++) 
    {
            //W[i][j] += lr * (ph_mean[i] * input[j] - nh_means[i] * nv_means[j]);
            // trying to compute the Gaussian visible units

            W[i][j] += lr * (pow(ph_mean[i] * input[j])*(ph_mean[i] * input[j])/2 - nh_means[i] * nv_means[j]);
    }
    hbias[i] += lr * (nh_means[i] - ph_mean[i]);
}
```

Comment: What result do you expect from the function `pow(x)`? May be you are trying to calculate square of `x` (i.e. `x*x`)? Or square root of `x` (i.e. `sqrt(x)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `pow(ph_mean[i] * input[j])*(ph_mean[i] * input[j])` to

```
pow((ph_mean[i] * input[j]),2)
```

that will evaluate the square of the product for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `pow` takes two arguments with no defaults:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Comment: It worked when computing the error :  err += sqrt(pow(train_X[i*n_visible+j] - reconstructed_X[i+j], 2))/numbTraining_sample;

Comment: Indeed, note that in your working example you have a second parameter with value 2.